# AddHandler for pushpins in Bing Maps

Tags: vb.net, bing-maps

[VB2012] I am repeatedly adding pushpins from a database to a Bing Maps WPF MapLayer (ml) using the following code:

```
Dim pp As New Pushpin()
pp.Location = New Location(utm.Latitude.GetDecimalCoordinate, utm.Longitude.GetDecimalCoordinate)
pp.PositionOrigin = PositionOrigin.BottomCenter
pp.Content = PinLabel
pp.ToolTip = PinLabel
pp.FontSize = 6.0R
' need to put an AddHandler in here
ml.Children.Add(pp)
```

The pushpins are added and displayed on the maplayer.  What I don't understand is how to add the AddHandler for each pushpin so that I can determine when a pushpin is clicked.  I would really appreciate some insight.  I'm just not getting what I need to do from the online examples I have found.

Comment: If you type in Addhandler pp. are there any events that pop up in intellisense for that object? Is it this object on this site - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427615.aspx?

Comment: That is the right class except that we nees the WPF version.  There is nothing for AddHandler pp, but pp has a built in AddHandler. pp.AddHandler(routedEvent as System.RoutedEvent, handler as System.Delgate).  I'm confused by this routedevent.  How do I implement this?

Comment: In WPF the Addhandler statement is the same construction as in other VB.Net applications. `Addhandler pp.Click, AddressOf pp_click`. You have to make the sub routine with the signature that matches the event.

Comment: Thanks DonA.  Click is not part of the PushPin, but MouseLeftButtonDown is.  After I put in the AddHandler statement, VS stubbed in the sub for it.

Comment: OK, so how do I mark the question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF the Addhandler statement is the same construction as in other VB.Net applications. Since all Pushpins are routed to this event, the sender object will get you the right one.

```
Addhandler pp.MouseDown, AddressOf pp_MouseDown
```

You have to make the sub routine with the signature that matches the event.

```
Private Sub pp_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
  'sender is the PushPin in question
  Dim pp as PushPin = DirectCast(sender, PushPin)
End Sub
```